# Get List of related objects - Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How do I use django's queryset to get a list of users from the MyUser table where transaction_paid is False in my UserBankTransaction table?

```
class UserBankTransaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    plaid_transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    charge_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    location_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    roundup_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
    transaction_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True,)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address',max_length=255,unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True,)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True, blank=True,)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What if there are multiple transactions? Do you want users with *all* transactions unpaid, or *any* transaction unpaid.

Comment: Users with any transaction unpaid @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: The title of this post should be "how do i filter on a related object" if you're not actually querying the transaction model...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Querying with backward relationship will do:

```
MyUser.objects.filter(userbanktransaction_set__transaction_paid=False)
```

Comment: Im getting the following error - `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'userbanktransaction_set' into field. Choices are: created, email, first_name, id, is_active, is_admin, is_member, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, payment, paymentdata, pledge, updated, useralert, userbanktransaction, userchapter, userfinance, username, userprofile, userschool`

Comment: It seems that the default reverse lookup name does not have a `_set` suffix as I remembered. Try instead: `MyUser.objects.filter(userbanktransaction__transaction_paid=False)`

Comment: and what would be the best way if i want to filter the transactions by date, for example, only those that happened in the past 10 days ?

Comment: i know i can filter the transactions first, then retrieve the list of user IDs, and from that querying the MyUser model, but i'm curious to know if there's another wat

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to retrieve a list of user IDs:

```
UserBankTransaction.objects \
    .filter(transaction_paid=False)\
    .values_list('user', flat=True)
```

If you are going to retrieve a list of user objects:

```
MyUser.objects.filter(userbanktransaction_set__transaction_paid=False)
```

or your can specify a `related_name` in `UserBankTransaction.user`:

```
class UserBankTransaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='bank_transactions')
```

then you can simply do this:

```
MyUser.objects.filter(bank_transactions__transaction_paid=False)
```